# Python Multiprocessing Freeing up memory used by shared array

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Is there a way to deallocate the memory used by a shared Multiprocessing Array ? Here is a code snippet that creates a memory block of approx 1 GiB of shared memory which is then blocked for the remainder of the script. Is there a way to free up that memory during the same script run ?

I tried deleting all references and calling the garbage collector via gc.collect() but that seems to have no effect whatsoever on the Memory usage of the script during runtime.

```
import psutil
import gc
import ctypes as cty
import multiprocessing as mpc
import os

def bytes_to_GiB_MiB(n_bytes):
    return n_bytes/2**30, (n_bytes%(2**30))/2**20
    
def print_mem_usage():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid()) 
    print "Script Mem Usage {:} GiB {:} MiB".format(*bytes_to_GiB_MiB(process.memory_info().rss))
    return process.memory_info().rss    
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    t_N = 5000
    N=150
    Shape_spl = (t_N+4, N,N) 
    mem0 = print_mem_usage()
    C_shared = mpc.Array(cty.c_double, N*N*(t_N+4))
    mem1 = print_mem_usage()
    print "Mem Difference is {:} GiB {:} MiB".format(*bytes_to_GiB_MiB(mem1-mem0))
    del C_shared
    gc.collect()
    # Do something here such that the memory used by C_shared is free again.
    mem2 = print_mem_usage()
    print "Mem Difference is {:} GiB {:} MiB".format(*bytes_to_GiB_MiB(mem2-mem0))
```

Comment: The problem is resolved in Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 22:29:32) \n[GCC 7.3.0]. I tested the script initially with Python 2.7, there the memory is not released. With the new python the memory is released. I am still interested if there is a workaround for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... for the record... This seems to be related to this bug in python <= 3.7
(as already mentioned, it is supposed to be fixed in python 3.8):
https://bugs.python.org/issue32759

There's also a crude "fix" suggested in the discussion which seems to work for me with python 3.7:
(not sure if this also works in python 2.7)

> "... delete the globe _heap and recreate a new one"
> `mp.heap.BufferWrapper._heap = mp.heap.Heap()`